# Converting a german text to english text in vb6.0

Tags: vb6

i am a newbie to vb 6.0 ,i want to convert the german text to english text as one of 
my requirement can anybody help me with this.

thanks

Comment: Are you trying to translate your software, or does your software translate text for the end user?

Answer (score 1):

One way you could achieve this is to create a string resource DLL.  Have a look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232625) article for an example of how to use this.  When you have this, you can either make calls to the equivelent of LoadString() in the example for every resource or, alternatively, you could write a control to add to every form that automated this process (i.e. itterate through each control and replace the text based on the locale).